# Using DatagramSocket and python socket with devices connected to hotspot

Tags: android, sockets, udp, datagram

I have an Android app written using the `DatagramSocket` library, and Python server on my laptop written using the `socket` library.

They both communicate with each other.

When the Android phone and laptop are connected to my home internet it works fine. Standard out-of-the-box router setup.

However, when I connect the phone and laptop to a mobile hotspot it won't work. I need this functionality for a demonstration in college, as the college wifi doesn't work either.

Any suggestions what's causing the hotspot not to work, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: What about the ip addresses you are using?

Comment: The one's broadcasted by client and server. Broadcasting still working

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you able to ping the mobile device from the laptop? Are the ip address you are using the ones assigned by the hotspot? Could you be trying to run on a privileged port (below 1024)? Could the hotspot have client isolation enabled?

Comment: Pinging works, ports used are 11026 and 36883. I'm not sure what client isolation is, and how to check if it is enabled (it is in iPhone). I will check errors soon

Comment: I don't have this kind of experience using the iPhone internet sharing as a real router. And I haven't found anything conslusive on the web either. The few links I have found seem to point out that the functionality provided is meant to share internet only.

Comment: Were you able to do something? If so could you please look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/61215787/8608146?